# Upgrading Craft 2 to Craft 3 Yii Issues

Tags: upgrades

I tried searching for an answer for my situation but I could not find one. I tried following the steps here https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html#preparing-for-the-upgrade but whenever I get to the browser step to complete upgrade, I get this error:

> !/usr/bin/env php
>   Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: craft\console\User::enableSession'
>
> in /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:154
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/App.php(372): yii\base\Component->__get('enableSession')
>
> 1 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/app.php(214): craft\helpers\App::logConfig()
>
> 2 [internal function]: {closure}()
>
> 3 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(503): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
>
> 4 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(351): yii\di\Container->invoke(Object(Closure), Array)
>
> 5 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Object(Closure))
>
> 6 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('log', true)
>
> 7 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(146): yii\base\Module->get('log', true)
>
> 8 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(508): craft\console\Application->get('log')
>
> 9 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(1133): yii\base\Application->getLog()
>
> 10 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(62): craft\console\Application->_preInit()
>
> 11 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\console\Application->init()
>
> 12 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
>
> 13 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(89): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
>
> 14 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(53): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
>
> 15 [internal function]: craft\console\Application->__construct(Array)
>
> 16 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(383): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
>
> 17 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(156): yii\di\Container->build('craft\console\A...', Array, Array)
>
> 18 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->get('craft\console\A...', Array, Array)
>
> 19 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(252): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
>
> 20 /Users/avalosju/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/console.php(31): require('/Users/avalosju...')
>
> 21 /Users/avalosju/craft/craft(21): require('/Users/avalosju...')
>
> 22 /Users/avalosju/craft/web/index.php(19): require_once('/Users/avalosju...')
>
> 23 {main}

Comment: What's on line 19 of your `web/index.php` file? Looks like it's doing something to load the `craft` console executable at `craft/craft`. `/Users/avalosju/craft/web/index.php(19): require_once('/Users/avalosju...')`

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/helpers/App.php#L370)

```
$isConsoleRequest = Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest();
if (!$isConsoleRequest && !Craft::$app->getUser()->enableSession) {
    return null;
}
```

For whatever reasons `Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest();` does not return `true` -> `!false` becomes `true` -> it tries to grab the `user` which **should** be an instance of `craft\web\User` to have the property `enableSession` but since it **is** a console request you receive `craft\console\User` which has not such a property.

I guess it's a bug or something

Comment: I tried reinstalling and it worked, but then I changed my web-server path in MAMP to another folder, then changed back and it's happening again. I wonder if there's a way to prevent this from happening